# Organise dates in excel into 2 month blocks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to organize dates in an excel spreadsheet into 2 month blocks. So if a date is in January or February, I'd like a function to return "Jan-Feb". If a date is in March or April, I'd like it to return "Mar-Apr" etc. I'm a complete novice at excel formulae. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more information on how your data is set up, what you've tried already, and how you want it to look in the end.

Comment: The dates are in column H in the spreadsheet. I've gotten it to work on a single date (16/06/2015) with the following formula:

=IF(OR(MONTH(H3)=5,MONTH(H3)=6),"May-June " & YEAR(H3),"")

I guess it could be achieved with 6 nested IF statements, but I wondering if there's a more elegant dynamic way to do it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first creating an index which lists all the possible month combinations. ie, in cells J1:J12, enter "1" "2"..."12". Then in K1:K12, enter "January-February" "January-February""March-April""March-April"..."November-December".

Then put this formula instead of what you have above:

```
 =index($K$1:$K$12,Match(Month(H3),$J$1:$J$12,0))
```

This works similar to a vlookup function - if you are more comfortable using vlookup, it would look like this:

```
 =vlookup(month(H3),$K$1:$J$12,2,0)
```

Basically either function searches column K for the number of the month in H3, and then it provides the text string that you have manually typed in that row in column J.